# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID (React with Node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, openssl, ssl-certificate

Please Help, I'm in a big trouble.
Actually, I'm learning Full Stack Web Development with React on Coursera.

I created the private key and certificate by typing the following at the prompt:

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > private.key
openssl req -new -key private.key -out cert.csr
openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -signkey private.key -out certificate.pem
```

These above commands created 3 files on the given location :- **private.key, certificate.pem and cert.csr**

And then i included this in www file:-

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/private.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/certificate.pem')
};

var secureServer = https.createServer(options,app);
```

After Integrating both React Client and Server, i was able to run my react app on Browser.

**But when i tried to access the React app using the Network IP address, it stops fetching data from server and on console i found this error message - net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID**

Please help, As i said i'm learning. I have no idea about this.
[image: Here is the Screenshot]